# Get Attribute option Id by Attribute admin value

Tags: attributes, custom-options, attribute-options

For a Magento Dropdown Attribute, it is possible to get an Attribute option Id by Attribute admin value?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose, you have an product attribute called "color" in Magento. You have the attribut admin value (e.g. Purple), and you want to find it’s value. The below code will help you get the value for it.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
echo $color_id = $attr->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionId("Purple");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it works only with the Default Store View option value, when I try with the admin value I get NULL

Comment: This does not seem to work always. Somehow we now have an attr option admin value that just DOES NOT return an id.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the admin value :

`echo $color_id = $attr->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionId("purple");`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is the only one that actually answers the question that was actually asked. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

i was face same problem the solution work for me. because the frontend store values were not added. this code work for me.

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','color');
    $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    if ($attr->usesSource()) {

    $attributeOptions = $attr ->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
        if($option['label']=='Purple'){
           echo $curattributeid=$option['value'];
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Code below checks if the attribute already have an option then return its id other wise add new option and return its id

```
    function addAttributeOption($attributeCode, $argValue) {
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);


        if ($attribute->usesSource()) {

           $id = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($argValue);
           if ($id) 
                return $id;
        }

         $value = array('value' => array(
            'option' => array(
                    ucfirst($argValue),
                    ucfirst($argValue)
                )
            )
        );

        $attribute->setData('option', $value);
        $attribute->save();

        //getting id of newly inserted option
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
        if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
            return $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($argValue);
        }
   }
```

Use it as

```
$this->addAttributeOption("uniform_type", "leotard");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the option ID of an attribute by the admin value. You can use the `eav/entity_attribute_option_collection` to achieve it:

```
$attributeCode = 'attr_code';
$attributeAdminValue = 'something';

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
    ->setStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
    ->addFieldToFilter('tdv.value', $attributeAdminValue);

if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
    echo $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```